# How copy a newly created 'image-file' of a bootable OS (created thru 'dd') back to a bootable OS, using the 'dd' command?

Tags: linux, boot, dd

I want to go from 'image-file' to 'bootable OS' using the dd command.

I had a bootable OS and copied it, via dd, creating an 'image-file'. Now I want to re-create the bootable OS.

I tried using:

```
"sudo dd if=/filepath/filename bs=16M of=/dev/sdx"
```

...but it did not work - I did not get a bootable OS.

The image-file is saved on an external hdd, so I don't see how I can use "/dev" in the 'if' part of the command.

I am copying the files to a micro-sd.

Comment: What does the image contains? If only the os system partition then it cannot boot, obviously. You'd need the bootloader in the MBR (for BIOS) or the ESP (EFI system partition for UEFI).

Comment: How did you copy the OS into the image previously?

Comment: @grawity "sudo dd if=/dev/sdx bs=16M of=/filepath/new.filename". It's the reverse of the command above, as you'll see. Thanks.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia The image is a full OS. Thanks.

Comment: Both commands look okay; what kind of system was the bootable image for? Was it a PC? (Was it BIOS or UEFI?) And is the destination system the same?

Comment: @grawity The image was debian 10; pc; yes, destination system the same; buster-desktop; no bios or uefi - single arm board computer. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that both the source _and_ the destination are ARM SBCs?

Comment: @grawity yes. i routinely copy over (dd) the OS and it works fine, whereby, 'if' and 'of' are both "=/dev/sdx". This is the first time that I have tried to do what I posted in the question above, using a different command, as you can see.

Comment: @grawity please see my answer below; I can mount the OS to access some files. I have some old bookmarks on there that i want to get to, but don't know how to. I will post a new question. Thanks for your help again!!

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct command: "sudo dd if=/filepath/filename bs=16M of=/dev/sdx".

I must have made an error with the command filepath the first time. I retried it and it works now.

However, I can not access the OS as I don't have the login password and username for the old OS.